# Is it possible to create one form page for all list item actions in Sharepoint?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

Sorry if this belongs on SP SE, if so please migrate.

I aplogize in advanced if my terminonlogy is off this is all new to me. I have a Sharepoint I am helping maintain. The Sharepoint has custom code (WSP's) that make up Sharepoint Lists/List items on the Sharepoint, which are created via code (.net C#). From what I'm seeing, in addition to creating the forms for creating new list items and defining the list items, you also set the url for each list item action (namely, when you click the checkbox next to a list item, the ribbon bar has buttons for "view" and "edit" which in theory you're supposed to set to the form page url's for, such as ViewItem.aspx, EditItem.aspx, etc). I can create a different page for viewing the list item and a different page for editing the list item of my custom list, but the problem is that view list item is identitical to edit list item with the exception that in "view list item" all the fields are turned to disabled once they are populated.

It seems extremely redundant to create a copy page of all the exact same logic as the edit page, plus the few extra lines of code to disable the fields once they've been populated. Is there another way (such as somehow altering the querystring generated by Sharepoint so I can add my own flag to indicate that the user is "viewing" the form instead of editing it)? I was able to use the same page for edit and new form because when you edit a list item SP adds the list item "ID" to the querystring paramater, but i dont see a parameter I could key off of to indicate that the form should be opened in "view" mode.

Comment: I know while working with a SharePoint site using Designer there is a separate form for each URL. That means if you create custom forms in designer you have there is an option to edit all three forms. Not sure what that would mean while trying to got at it from code.